# How can I filter all rows that have something1 followed by xyz and to store them in a separate pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame looking like below.

INPUT

```
col1
```

0   something1
1   xyz
2   something1
3   abc
4   something1
5   xyz
6   something1
7   xyz

OUTPUT

```
col1
```

0   something1
4   something1
6   something1

Answer (score 0):

Create a  new subset of your df filtering the value you want on col1

```
df_output = df[df['col1']== 'something1']
```

or if you want just a df with values grouped ie sorted then

```
data = {'col':["something1"
, "something2"
, "something1"
, "something3"
, "something1"
, "something2"
, "something1"
,"something2"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.sort_values(by='col')


col
0   something1
2   something1
4   something1
6   something1
1   something2
5   something2
7   something2
```

Comment: This does not capture the solution OP needs. OP needs "something1", followed by "something2"

Comment: If you want just to sort values then `df.sort_values(by='col')`

Comment: I don't want to sort the values, I want to get the values which are preceding 'something2' in the column.